# How to sample groups in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with about > 1M groups and each group contains about ~100 records (rows). How do I sample based on the distinct groups in pyspark so that the selected groups will still have the complete rows?

A much smaller example:

```
+-----+---+
|group| x |
+-----+---+
|  1  |0.1|
|  1  |0.2|
|  2  |0.1|
|  2  |0.5|
|  2  |0.3|
|  3  |0.5|
|  4  |0.8|
|  4  |0.5|
+-----+---+
```

I want to sample so that if group 1 and 3 are selected I got complete records from them:

```
+-----+---+
|group| x |
+-----+---+
|  1  |0.1|
|  1  |0.2|
|  3  |0.5|
+-----+---+
```

Comment: Do you already have the selected groups or you need to sample it first?

Comment: You can sample on the `group` column and join that back to your original dataframe

Comment: @Psidom I need to sample group first.

Comment: @pault Good call!